# what is the best solution for a single board camera module

Tags: camera

I am looking for a single board computer that can connect to two camera and save images from both camera at the frame rate of around 5-6 fps into a hard disk?

What is the best single board computer that I can buy?

Comment: Actually, this can likely be accomplished with a Raspberry Pi 2, or a Parallella board, using a USB hub.  The capture to HDD and framerate settings would be more a function of configuration of the OS though.    Not sure how this question is all that broad.

Comment: @NZKshatriya: RPI can not handle more than 2k1k (HD) for capture and stream. If you want to capture 5mpixel or 8 mpixel and convert to jpeg, it takes 500 ms (2 frame per second) . I am not sure about Parallela, as I can not see any code or camera which is compatible with this board.

Comment: How about the [NVIDIA JETSON TK1](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813190005&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Motherboard+%2F+CPU+%2F+VGA+Sets-_-N82E16813190005&gclid=CLiUgIXhntACFQgzaQodKf4LiQ&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: I just don't see how a single board computer, with specified requirements equates to too broad of a topic >.<

Comment: @NZKshatriya I can not find a suitable camera module for it. I am sure that the board can handle the 4K requirement, but I can not find the camera module.